# Given $B>0$, and $c_1,c_2>0$, does there exist $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, such that $ABA^*= \operatorname{diag}\{c_1,c_2\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For the given $c_1>0,c_2>0$, and positive definite matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, does there exist $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, such that $ABA^*= \operatorname{diag}\{c_1,c_2\}$?

I know that since $B>0$, there exists nonsingular $D$, such that $DBD^*=I$.

Is there way to to push ones in identity to $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: Is $^*$ the transpose? Because if so, the result that you claim to "know" does not seem true at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia). Alternatively, orthogonally diagonalise $B$ first and solve for $A$. You may also solve the equations $XBX^T=I$ and $I=Y\operatorname{diag}(c_1,c_2)Y^T$ individually for real invertible matrices $X$ and $Y$, and set $A$ to $Y^{-1}X$.

Comment: thanks for help